# What is the menu item Automatic Updates for iOS when you have to start them manually?

Tags: ios, software-update

So far, no iOS update has started automatically. Do you have to consider anything else?

Comment: "You will receive a notification before updates are installed. Your iPhone must be charging and connected to WiFi to complete the update." There must also have been an update available since you switched this on. Does all the above apply?

Comment: It was not charging.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the Apple Support document, [Update your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204204):

> #### Update automatically
>
> With iOS 12 or later, or iPadOS, you can have your device update automatically. To turn on automatic updates, go to Settings > General > Software Update, then tap Automatic Updates. Your device will automatically update to the latest version of iOS or iPadOS. Some updates might need to be installed manually.

Here's the conditions to be met for automatic updates to install:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2AHY.jpg]